# Duda con implementación de decoradores

Tags: python, clase, decoradores

Estoy tratando de implementar esta clase la cual tiene dentro un método `insertar()` que es decorado por `@ejecutar`.
A su vez este quiero decorarlo con `@conectar`.
Al hacer correr el programa no me tira ningún error, aunque todavía no use el método `insertar`.
Mi pregunta es: ¿se pueden decorar métodos dentro de una misma clase?.
De ser así, ¿los `self` que coloqué dentro de los decoradores, están bien ubicados?.

Pregunto porque no he encontrado ningún ejemplo hecho así, y quizás esté mal implementado.
Los ejemplos que vi son de una clase que actúa como decorador sobre funciones externas a ellas.
Creo que sobre otras clases también... gracias, saludos.

```py
class Consulta():
        
    def __init__(self):
        self._conexion = None
        self._cursor = None
        self._registro = None
        
    def conectar(func):

        def inner_con(self, *args, **kwargs):

            try:
                self._conexion = sqlite3.connect('escuela.db')
                func(self, *args, **kwargs)

            except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
                messagebox.showerror(title="ERROR!", message=e)

            finally:
                if self._conexion:
                    self._conexion.close()

        return inner_con
        
    @conectar 
    def ejecutar(func):

        def inner_ej(self, *args, **kwargs):
            
            try:
                self._cursor = self._conexion.cursor()
                sentencia, valor = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                self._cursor.execute(sentencia, valor)
                self._conexion.commit()
                self._cursor.close()

            except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
                messagebox.showerror(title="ERROR!", message=e)
                self._conexion.rollback()

        return inner_ej
        
    @ejecutar
    def insertar(self, tabla='', columnas='', listado='', contenido=''): 
        lista_cv = (contenido, )
        orden = f"INSERT INTO {tabla}({columnas}) VALUES({listado});"
        return orden, lista_cv
```

Answer (score 1):

En general, por ser python un lenguaje dinámico, no verás ningún error en tu código hasta el momento de ejecutar el método `insertar`.

Los decoradores que has definido esperan una función. Pero si los defines como métodos, lo que van a recibir como primer argumento será una instancia, lo que normalmente llamamos `self`, por lo que no van a funcionar como esperas.

Estos decoradores no tienen ninguna necesidad de estar dentro de la clase. Lo recomendable sería sacarlos fuera de la clase como funciones separadas.

Si aún así deseas que estén dentro, deben ser declarados como *métodos estáticos*:

```py
class Consulta():

    @staticmethod
    def conectar(func):

        def inner_con(self, *args, **kwargs):
            ...  # código que invoca a func
        
        return inner_con
```

Luego quieres usarlo para decorar otro método que, a su vez, será también decorador, por lo que tendrás que declararlo también como estático:

```py
class Consulta():

    ...

    @Consulta.conectar 
    @staticmethod
    def ejecutar(func):

        def inner_ej(self, *args, **kwargs):
            ... # código que invoca a func

        return inner_ej
```

Como método estático tienes que invocarlo relacionándolo con la clase, por eso se pone `Consulta.conectar`.

Y finalmente, en el método `insertar`:

```py
class Consulta():

    ...

    @Consulta.ejecutar
    def insertar(self, tabla='', columnas='', listado='', contenido=''): 
        ...
```

No sé si te funcionará tal cual. Si falla algo, lo comentas y lo vemos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta tan completa, pero ahora me tira el siguente error:    @Consulta.conectar
NameError: name 'Consulta' is not defined
Ahora mi pregunta es, para usar estos decoradores y ubicarlos fuera de la clase, los hago como simples decoradores, en tal caso como los llamo para q trabajen dentro de consulta o debo hacer una clase que sea la que decore a esta clade

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta tan completa, pero ahora me tira el siguiente error:    @Consulta.conectar
NameError: name 'Consulta' is not defined
Ahora mi pregunta es, para usar estos decoradores y ubicarlos fuera de la clase, los hago como simples decoradores, en tal caso como los llamo para que trabajen dentro de Consulta o debo hacer una clase que sea la que decore a esta clase Consulta? ... también vi un ejemplo donde definían los decoradores en un modulo a parte y luego los importaban a la clase donde querían usarlos

Comment: Para cuando el intérprete llega a la línea `@Consulta.conectar` aún no ha terminado de definir la clase `Consulta` así que no reconoce ese símbolo. Como estás dentro de la clase `Consulta` puedes invocar `@conectar`.

Comment: Sospechaba que te daría ese error. En python no puedes referenciar una clase antes de que esté definida (en lenguajes compilados sí que es posible). Mi recomendación es que pongas los decoradores fuera de la clase en el mismo fichero. Si los vas a utilizar en más clases entonces sí que podrías llevarlos a otro módulo para facilitar su reutilización. Los decoradores son simplemente "funciones" que usan una función como argumento y retornan una función. Incluso los decoradores que decoran clases lo que hacen es decorar el constructor, aunque aquí sería mejor pensar en usar "metaclases".

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomiendo que saques los decoradores de la clase `Consulta`, ya que no usan ni sus métodos ni sus atributos.

```
def conectar(func):
    def inner_con(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    return inner_con

@conectar
def ejecutar(func):
    def inner_ej(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    return inner_ej

class Consulta:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        
    @ejecutar
    def insertar(self, tabla='', columnas='', listado='', contenido=''): 
        ...
```

Es necesario que el decorador `ejecutar` esté definido antes de usarlo en la clase `Consulta`.

Tal y como está escrito, el decorador `conectar` no parece que lo puedas aplicar a `ejecutar`.
`conectar` espera decorar una función cuyo primer argumento (`self`) sea de tipo `Consulta`.
Sin embargo está decorando una función, `ejecutar`, cuyo único argumento es una función, `func`.
Si no me equivoco, lo que quieres es concatenar ambos decoradores.
Para ello, tendrías que quitar el decorador `conectar` de `ejecutar`.
Después añadimos ambos decoradores a `insertar`:

```
@conectar
@ejecutar
def insertar(...):
    ...
```

Quizás puedes incluso definir un tercer decorador que aplique los dos anteriores consecutivamente:

```
def conectar_y_ejecutar(func):
    return ejecutar(conectar(func))
```

---

Si quieres que tu editor de código reconozca correctamente el atributo `self` dentro de `inner_con` y `inner_ej`, puedes usar anotaciones.
Como los decoradores los defines cuando `Consulta` aún no está definido, tendrás que escribir el nombre de la clase entre comillas:

```
def conectar(func):
    def inner_con(self: 'Consulta', *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    return inner_con
```